# Why does this type cast in Java with a fraction work?

Tags: java, casting

```
 double frac = (double) 3/2
```

For the longest time I thought this would only cast the result of the int division to double, but frac has the intended value of 1.5. Why does this work?

Answer (score 2):

```
double frac = (double) 3/2;
```

is equivalent to

```
double frac = ((double) 3)/2;
```

first 3 is cast to `double` (and becomes `3.0`), and then floating point division is performed, returning `1.5`.

If the division was performed prior to the casting as in

```
double frac = (double) (3/2);
```

the result would be `1.0`, since integer division would have been performed prior to the casting.